# Netlogo: randomly transform breed

Tags: netlogo

I'm working on a rebellion simulation and I'm trying to use Netlogo but I'm new to it so I'm running into some issues. I'm working off a modified wolf sheep model and I have three turtle types: police, rebels, and civilians. I have the general set up working but I'm trying to incorporate a civilian collateral damage element.

I want to model the police imperfectly differentiating rebels and civilians. When police mistakenly arrest a civilian, that causes *n* other number of random civilians to then become rebels. Where I get lost is interacting the police's actions with the civilian breed type. Below is my police procedure for civilian arrests:

```
to collateral-damage ;police procedure  
    let prey one-of civilians-here 
    if prey != nobody and random 100 < prob-collateral
    [ ask prey [ die ]  ]
```

Any help is super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Breed can be set like any other turtle owned variable, with a `set` statement. There's not quite enough detail to give you a definitive answer, but I think you want something like:

```
let prey one-of civilians-here 
if prey != nobody and random 100 < prob-collateral
[ ask prey [set breed rebels]
  ask n-of min (list 5 count civilians) [set breed rebels]
]
```

Comment: Thanks responding! What additional details should I provide? I'm a little unclear on what qualifies as a reproducible example for Netlogo here. 

Also, looking at the code wouldn't that just change the captured civilian into a rebel? What would I need to generalize it so that 'n' number of civilians become rebels?

Comment: Yes, reproducible examples are almost impossible with NetLogo. A good rule of thumb is to give the whole of the problem procedure, the procedure that calls the problem procedure and any relevant `globals`, `turtles-own` or `patches-own` declarations so that it's clear what variable is owned by what.

Comment: have edited to also do 5 random civilians (the min is to ensure you don't ask for 5 when there are fewer than 5 remaining)